# How to remove a class from a check in a jQuery Mobile Table

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a check box inside a jQuery Mobile table with an id of `DeleteTable` and it has the following class added to it:

[image]

I simply want to remove the class `ui-checkbox` I have the following code:

```
$("TableDelete input[type='checkbox'] div").removeClass("ui-checkbox");
```

But this somehow doesn't seem to work and I'm sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

```
$("TableDelete .ui-checkbox").removeClass("ui-checkbox");
```

On the other hand, you mustn't be doing this. If you dont want styling to be applied to an element, for example, your checkbox, must have a `data-role=none` in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply the data-role='none' worked perfectly

Comment: glad to be of help :) pls upvote the answer if you think it will help future visitors :)